# Secure specific pages on backend

Tags: security, content-management-system

Have a client that wants to use a certain software CMS for redesigning their site.  There will be approximately 5 people that should have access only to certain, specific pages on the backend to modify.  Is there a command that will allow that in HTML?

Mike

Answer (score 0):

If your CMS is being served by Apache web server then you can use htpasswd and htaccess for securing your CMS. http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/